# Nominal type roles and data families

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

I understand why the new [role system and annotations](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/roles.html) require type (and data) family parameters to be at role `nominal`.

So I expected when I declared

```
data family CoordinateRepresentation ty a :: *
```

that `ty` and `a` would get `nominal` roles. (My actual example is an associated data family, but since I don't think it changes anything I am omitting the extra noise that comes with that.)

What I didn't expect is that when I changed it to

```
data family CoordinateRepresentation ty :: * -> *
```

is that the unnamed second type argument still gets a `nominal` role.

Why is this? Couldn't it safely get a `representational` role, because doesn't any `data instance CoordinateRepresentation ... = ...` have to create a fresh constructor? How could that constructor have the opportunity to use its parameter at a `nominal` role in a way that the compiler can't see? Even though it's an open system and there is separate compilation, I still don't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a first, minor point: Whether a data family is declared with type variables or with kind signature is currently entirely immaterial, they are just different syntaxes for the same thing. From [the GHC User's Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html#data-families) on data family declarations:

> Just as with [GADT declarations](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/gadt.html) named arguments are entirely optional, [...]

The major point remains, and has been discussed in [this GHC trac thread](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8177). Short summary: It is possible, by adding role inference and/or role annotations for data/type families, but it is not yet implemented.

Comment: Ah, I see. I expected that the second syntax would limit the "pattern matching" part of the type family to the first argument and require the resulting `* -> *` to be in some sense "ordinary", but that isn't the case.